# React .map returns undefined with Fetch API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api, array.prototype.map

I want my React `render` method to return objects from an API in a similar way to what I get from Postman. For example:

```
{
  "meta": {
    "count": 807,
    "countReturned": 10,
    "requestTime": 1552524395,
    "responseTime": 1552524395,
    "responseMs": 7
  },
  "data": [
     {
        "type": "breeds",
        "id": "1",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Abyssinian"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "species": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "type": "species",
                        "id": "3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "meta": []
    },
```

But I'm having trouble using .map to produce the object(s) I want. Here is my code:

```
class Results extends Component {
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        animals: [],
    };
}

componentDidMount() {
    var url = "https://test1-api.rescuegroups.org/v5/public/animals/breeds?fields[breeds]=name&fields[species]=singular,plural,youngSingular,youngPlural&include=species&options=meta&limit=10";
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: API_KEY,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => this.setState({animals: data.results }))
}

render() {
    return (

        <div>
            {this.state.animals.map(animal => <div>{animal.results}</div>)}
        </div>

    )
}
}

export default Results;
```

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: `then(data => this.setState({animals: data.results }))`, according to your json, there is no `results` field in it.

Comment: I know! I should have clarified that better I have tried data.type as well as a level deeper data.type.breeds which both throw errors. I should have not used results in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter of the callback method named 'data' doesn't mean it's a `data` property of the response data.

I think the callback should be

```
...
.then(response => response.json())
.then(response => this.setState({animals: response.data}))

<div>
  {this.state.animals.map(animal => <div>{animal.type}</div>)}
</div>
```

Comment: Yup I didn't understand 'data' was something I was defining myself. I need to figure out how to get keys working (combining your answer with Parth Patel's) but at least I'm seeing data rendered that I can work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the JSON data you are getting is correct, then you can loop over the object using the following code.

```
 Object.keys(this.state.animals).map((key) => {
    return <div value={key}>{ this.state.animals[key] }</div>
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is confusing you because of a slightly confusing naming convention you have. Your `componentDidMount` function will need to look as follows:

```
componentDidMount() {
    var url = "https://test1-api.rescuegroups.org/v5/public/animals/breeds?fields[breeds]=name&fields[species]=singular,plural,youngSingular,youngPlural&include=species&options=meta&limit=10";
    const API_KEY = process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY;

    fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            Authorization: API_KEY,
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => this.setState({animals: json.data }))
}
```

You need to pull the `data` key out of the response, which, with your current naming, would be `data.data`.

In your render function, you will then use the `animals` from your state. If you wanted the name of the animal, you would use the following:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (

        <div>
            {this.state.animals.map(animal => <div>{animal.attributes.name}</div>)}
        </div>

    )
}
```